# How does the skip() method in InputStream work?

Tags: java

```
InputStream is = new URL(someUrl).openStream();
long length = is.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

When I call `is.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE)`, does it download the file before returning the value, or does it actually skip the given number of byte (assume the size is less than `MAX_VALUE`)?

Comment: The only way to know is to read the code.

Comment: ... and that is likely to be JVM dependant, but see my answer anyway.

Answer (score 8):

If you trace around the OpenJDK (assuming you have a network connection) you get to `SocketInputStream.skip(long)`

```
/**
 * Skips n bytes of input.
 * @param n the number of bytes to skip
 * @return  the actual number of bytes skipped.
 * @exception IOException If an I/O error has occurred.
 */
public long skip(long numbytes) throws IOException {
    if (numbytes <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    long n = numbytes;
    int buflen = (int) Math.min(1024, n);
    byte data[] = new byte[buflen];
    while (n > 0) {
        int r = read(data, 0, (int) Math.min((long) buflen, n));
        if (r < 0) {
            break;
        }
        n -= r;
    }
    return numbytes - n;
}
```

This appears to read all the data until the connection is closed (or you read 9 Exa-bytes ;)

EDIT: The maximum read size of 1024 bytes is slightly surprising given packets of 1.5 KB is fairly common (when sends lots of data)

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#skip%28long%29):

> Skips over and discards n bytes of data from the input stream.
>
> The skip method may, for a variety of reasons, end up skipping over some smaller number of bytes, possibly 0. If n is negative, an IOException is thrown, even though the skip method of the InputStream superclass does nothing in this case. The actual number of bytes skipped is returned.
>
> This method may skip more bytes than are remaining in the backing file. This produces no exception and the number of bytes skipped may include some number of bytes that were beyond the EOF of the backing file. Attempting to read from the stream after skipping past the end will result in -1 indicating the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the implementation of the [JDK6 HTTP client](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/ef3efe6d9488/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/http/), you see no special handling of the `skip` method. That means that (by default, assuming you don't do something elaborate like configuring a range header on the request) you'll be reading all those bytes one chunk at a time. The chunk size is itself variable (Peter Lawrey makes a good case for it being 1024 bytes) but will be bounded by the MTU at the IP layer, i.e. usually around 1500 bytes.

That code as posted will download the whole file. Sorry.

Comment: Of course, it wouldn't actually be safe for the low-level code to be doing a lot of assumptions with range headers either; it doesn't know whether the resource at the other end can be treated like a file or if it has to be careful about how many times it downloads something.

Comment: Yes, i want to find another way to get Size of an InputStream, help me!

Comment: @TranduyKhoa A general InputStream doesn't know. With HTTP specifically, you could try doing a HEAD to get the Content-Length header; that _might_ work (or the HTTP server might not know either, or it might be unwilling to tell you). Better to ask this all as a full separate question though.

Answer (score 0):

Skip method will skip chunks of bytes which you have passed. 
For more information see 
http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/corejava/zip/skip.html

Answer (score -1):

Skips over and discards n bytes of data from the input stream. The skip method may, for a variety of reasons, end up skipping over some smaller number of bytes, possibly 0. The actual number of bytes skipped is returned.

for example see this:
[skip() example](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/corejava/zip/skip.html)

Comment: What other reasons are there? How can I tell it to skip up to X bytes, and then know if it really reached the end ? It says that reaching the end is only one reason. In a loop to skip X bytes, should I always check the value of "skip", that if it's 0, I should stop it?