# How do i start reading byte through input stream from a specific Location in the stream?

Tags: java

I am using URL class in java and I want to read bytes through Input Stream from a specific byte location in the stream instead of using skip() function which takes a lot of time to get to that specific location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it is not possible and here is why: when you send GET request, remote server does not know that you are interested in bytes from 100 till 200 - he sends you full document/file. So you need to read them, but don't need to handle them - that is why skip is slow.
But: I am sure that you can tell server (some of them support it, some - don't) that you want 100+ bytes of file.
Also: see this to get in-depth knowledge about skip mechanics: [How does the skip() method in InputStream work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077055/how-does-the-skip-method-in-inputstream-work#)

Comment: I was assuming that if some how i could give the offset and fetch the bytes from that address but from answers i think skip is only way to get to the desired byte location

Comment: @Datta - It is not the only solution.  Read my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

The nature of streams mean you will need to read through all the data to get to the specific place you want to start from. You will not get faster than `skip()` unfortunately.

Comment: thnx for ur instant answer I was assuming that i could give it a offset and get the bytes from that address but i think i am stuck with the skip

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you can't.

If you perform a GET that requests the entire file, you will have to use `skip()` to get to the part that you want.  (And in fact, the slowness is most likely because the server has to send all of the data that is being skipped to the client.  That is how TCP/IP works ...)

However, there is a possible alternative.  The HTTP 1.1 specification supports partial fetching documents using the [`Range` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35).  If your server supports this, then you can request the server to send you just the range of the document that you are interested in.  However, you may need to deal with the case where the server ignores the Range header and sends the entire document anyway.

Comment: Thnx for the instant answer and i think i have no other way than to use skip i was assuming that if i could give the offset and get the bytes from that address in the stream.